# How to slide all images to left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to create a slideshow with jQuery.

This is what I have tried:

```js
$('.images').animate({right: "200px"}, 1500)
```

```css
.slideshow {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slideshow img {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.images {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="images">
  <img src="https://store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.24119.13561428843663101.db53229a-3063-4dd3-b18e-61ad6b3661d1.b2b9b3b6-0326-402e-be19-4fe9ce86f784?mode=scale&q=90&h=200&w=200&background=%230078D7" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/Thinkstock/1095407386.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/IllustrationsLanding/img_88472599.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
</div>
```

The first image slides left but the background stays red. How can I make the other two images slide left as well?

If I use width: 2000px for the class .slideshow, it works great but not if the width is 200px.

Comment: You are sliding not an image you are sliding the whole container at once. You have to slide one image after the other when one image has finished.

Comment: @cloned I have tried it with `$('img').animate({right: "200px"}, 1500)` but the result is the same.

Comment: add `white-space: nowrap;` to the image container

Comment: @TemaniAfif that works great. Thank you!